# Importing NULL for decimal type MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following schema

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| NDB_No      | char(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| FdGrp_Cd    | char(4)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Long_Desc   | char(200)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Shrt_Desc   | char(60)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ComName     | char(100)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ManufacName | char(65)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Survey      | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Ref_desc    | char(135)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Refuse      | decimal(2,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SciName     | char(65)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| N_Factor    | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Pro_Factor  | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Fat_Factor  | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CHO_Factor  | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When trying to import this line

```
01002^0100^Butter, whipped, with salt^BUTTER,WHIPPED,W/ SALT^NULL^NULL^Y^NULL^0^NULL^6.38^NULL^NULL^NULL
```

I'm met with an error

```
1366 Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'Pro_Factor' 
1366 Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'Fat_Factor' 
1366 Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'CHO_Factor'
```

And the data is imported as `0.00`

```
'01002', '0100', 'Butter, whipped, with salt', 'BUTTER,WHIPPED,W/ SALT', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'Y', 'NULL', '0', 'NULL', '6.38', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'
```

Currently, I'm using MySQLWorkbench to import the data from a local file

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'FOOD_DES.txt' 
INTO TABLE usda_sr28.FOOD_DES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: How do you import data? Is it a tool? A script? From error message you quoted I am guessing that NULL is imported as a string 'NULL' and not as a NULL value.

Comment: I edited to show the script I'm using

Comment: Try to replace NULL in your source file with \N as per: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `load data infile` you can use `set`:

```
load data infile . . .
    (ndb_no, . . ., @pro, @fat, @cho, . . .)
    set pro_factor = nullif(@pro, 'NULL'),
        fat_factor = nullif(@fat, 'NULL'),
        cho_factor = nullif(@cho, 'NULL')
```

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) has more details.